# Google Analytics - Filtering Sub Domain - apart from one url

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

Hello we would like to filter all of a sub domain apart from one url within a view.

This is the sub domain we would like to exclude:
sub.ourwebsite.co.uk

but we want to be able to track successful sign ups.

The signup workflow is

1) ourwebsite.co.uk                    (this is our sales website)

2) sub.ourwebsite.co.uk\signupform     (this is the form they use to sign up with)

3) sub.ourwebsite.co.uk\welcome        (this is a successful sign up)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing a include for the sub domain you can do an include which matches the following:

```
^oursite.co.uk*|^www.oursite.co.uk*|^live.oursite.co.uk/welcome|^live.oursite.co.uk/signupform
```